# How do I separate a SQL partition by category: "row_number() over (partition by..."?

Tags: sql

I am working with some app events data and looking to group the event sets of a specific action together, in order to grab the most recent event set. The customer (customer_id) starts the event set with 'step 1' (EventStep) and can go all the way through step 4 (or can drop out at any step along the way). The event set can be triggered by a few actions (EventTrigger).

**Goal: Grab all the steps of the most recent event set, and identify the date (based on Timestamp) and EventTrigger.**

#### Issue

There should only be 1 EventTrigger for each event set but the way my code is written, it combined event steps from different EventTriggers ( if the customer advanced further along in previous attempts than in most recent attempts). How do I ensure the event steps are grouped by the EventTrigger?

#### My code

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT customer_id
         , EventStep
         , Timestamp
         , EventTrigger
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, EventStep ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS row_num
    FROM xxx_table
) xxx
WHERE row_num = 1
```

#### Actual Results

Image 1:
[image: actual results]

#### Wanted Results

Image 2
[image: wanted]

The `ID` field is something I created that labels the events in the order that they happened so that you can visualize what I'm looking for better.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please don't use links to images.  Please copy the data examples as formatted text in to your question.

Comment: Improve your question by [help/formatting]: e.g. give it structure using headings; embed images (e.g. `![actual results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsDjs.png)`, even better __post text instead images__ (where possible). Important: SQL questions should always have a __tag with DBMS__ used (since syntax differs).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want:

```
SELECT xxx.*
FROM (SELECT xxx.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, EventStep ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM xxx_table xxx
     ) xxx
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Nothing in your question suggests that aggregation is necessary.

EDIT:

Are you just looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
select xxx.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by Timestamp) as seqnum
from xxx_table xxx;
```

Comment: Thank you but that is not what I'm looking for. I don't think my question was clear, just added some edits - please check pictures of result set.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase, you want the most recent events for each customer, stopping at the most recent Step1?

```
SELECT
  xxx_table.*
FROM
  xxx_table
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT customer_id, MIN(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM xxx_table
   WHERE EventStep = 'Step 1'
)
  AS cust_endpoint
     ON  cust_endpoint.customer_id  = xxx_table.customer_id
     AND cust_endpoint.timestamp   >= xxx_table.timestamp
```